# Object prototype throws error even if object was not created in JS

Tags: javascript, oop

Help me grasp this please. I want to create object, which property "visible" and method "hi", but getting error on line 2:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'visible' of undefined

in:

```
var NewFilter = {};
NewFilter.prototype.visible = false;
NewFilter.hi = function () { console.info("hi"); }
```

OK I know that I have to actually create that object, but why the hell it's property throwing error when it should eventually do upon object creation?

Comment: Why are you setting `visible` on `prototype`?

Comment: Object instances do not have a `.prototype` property, the constructor function that created the instance does. What prototype is and what it can be used for is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063478/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty objects don't have a `prototype` property, so you can't set a property on it's (nonexistent) `prototype`.

Just set it on the object itself, instead:

```
var NewFilter = {};
NewFilter.visible = false;
NewFilter.hi = function () { console.info("hi"); }
```

If you want to learn more about JavaScript `prototype`s, I'd suggest looking for **[a](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) [tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) / [sites](http://1closure.com/2012/07/object-oriented-javascript-part-2-how-the-prototype-works/)**.

Comment: @sebcap26: Oh, indeed. Copied that from the question, fixed both :-) I believe the privileges on "small" edits come with [2k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)